# Input problems in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem when i create inputs from a button: https://jsfiddle.net/bg0cv2az/

```
let liberatePasswordButtonClickHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let idButtonPassword = $(e.currentTarget).closest('#password-changer')
    if (idButtonPassword = '#password-changer') {
        $(e.currentTarget).html(`<div class="left-column">
                   <div class="imput-wrapper top">
                     <div class="imput-title">
                       <span><strong>New passoword</strong></span>
                     </div>
                     <input type="password" placeholder="New passoword here"/>
                   </div>
                   <div class="imput-wrapper">
                     <div class="imput-title">
                       <span><strong>Re-enter new password</strong></span>
                     </div>
                     <input type="password" placeholder="Re-enter new password here"/>
                   </div>
                 </div>`)
    }

}
$(document).on('click', '#password-changer', liberatePasswordButtonClickHandler)
```

The inputs doesn't work, anyone know why?

Comment: Because you are binding to the whole document not just the button. So every click on the page replaces the inputs.

Comment: That `if` statement test is incorrect (`=` instead of `==`), so it always succeeds. If that typo were fixed, it would never succeed because `idButtonPassword` will be a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work as you are setting the entire content within `<button>` tag.

You can actually verify this,Click & Press the input. When you are pressed, you can actually type into the input element. But when you release everythign gets cleared. You are not able to get the edit button as `onClickListener` of button is active in foreground.

Simple solution is to clear the entire content and then add the html into `<div>`

```
...
if (idButtonPassword = '#password-changer') {
                $(e.currentTarget).parent().empty() // <- modified line
               .html(`<div class="left-column">
                   <div class="imput-wrapper top">
                     <div class="imput-title">
...
```

You can checkout the JSFiddleDemo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pvyamqth/)

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening is that every time you click on an input a whole new set of inputs are being generated and the old set is being replaced.

So if you click on anything inside `#password-changer` (a div) the signal gets propagated and you replace the whole insides of the div with new input.

If I understand the problem correctly this is a solution:

```
let liberatePasswordButtonClickHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#password-changer').html(`
        <div class="left-column">
        <div class="imput-wrapper top">
            <div class="imput-title">
                <span><strong>New passoword</strong></span>
            </div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="New passoword here"/>
        </div>
        <div class="imput-wrapper">
            <div class="imput-title">
                <span><strong>Re-enter new password</strong></span>
            </div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Re-enter new password here"/>
        </div>
      </div>`);
};
$(document).on('click', '#password-changer .button-edit', liberatePasswordButtonClickHandler)
```

Explanation:

- `$(document).on('click', '#password-changer .button-edit', liberatePasswordButtonClickHandler)` applies the function `liberatePasswordButtonClickHandler` any time a class `button-edit` is clicked inside a container with ID `password-changer`
- `$('#password-changer').html(...)` just simply replaces the internals of the parent div (this is simple because it has some ID)

If you wanted to make this more general you can:

- change `#password-changer` to `.password-changer` to reference a class instead of an ID
- Then inside when replacing your html do something like `$(e.target).parents('.password-changer').first().html(...)` (this gets the closest parent with class `password-changer`)